# Using jQuery, how do I append a PHP page to a DIV?

Tags: php, jquery

how do I append a PHP page to a div? I know the following will work:

```
$("#mycontainer").append( $('<div />').load('/myscript.php') );
```

...but what if I don't want it wrapped in a DIV?

Important to note that I want to APPEND and note replace the contents of "#mycontainer".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could use `$.ajax()` or `$.get()` instead:

```
$.get('/myscript.php', function(result) {
    $("#mycontainer").append(result);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One way

[.unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) the [.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) of `div` before u append it

```
$("#mycontainer").append(function () {
     return $('<div />').load('/myscript.php').contents().unwrap('div');
});
```

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work for me... div didn't unwrap. Maybe need to unwrap on load complete?

Comment: +1 for the solution but I accepted @Jason P cause he was first.

Answer (score 0):

To load something into an existing container (and replace its content), do this:

```
$("#mycontainer").load('/myscript.php');
```

To append (and keep current content), you need $.ajax() or $.get()

Comment: "Important to note that I want to APPEND and not replace..."